# Fixing Zebra Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I've followed the instruction on implementing this simple jQuery Accordion, however, it looks messy on the webpage. If you go to **Alchemy in Detail** Tab you'll see the Zebra Accordion in action. **http://www.planet.nu/dev/test/product-page.html**

It's very messy, but if you try opening the **Inspect Elements** on your web browser (Firefox ro Chrome) it fixes itself! But when you refresh the page, it will revert back to its messy layout.

I'm not sure if my html is broken or the css.

```html
<dl class="Zebra_Accordion">
  <dt>Managed Services</dt>
   <dd>
    <p><span>Alchemy Social’s Managed Service solution works with businesses of all sizes — from brand new start-ups to established multinationals — ensuring that they connect with and engage the right social audiences.</span></p>
    <p>Our teams combine the perfect blend of skills, from traditional digital display through search to creative design. With offices around the world, we manage campaigns and support our clients whenever and wherever they need us:</p>
     <ul class="alchemy-product-list-subnav">
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Full campaign management, from goal setting/strategy through to delivery and reporting </li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Dedicated Account Managers</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Targeting and segmentation planning</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Custom built creative generation on demand (image and copy)</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Daily optimisation</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Regular reporting</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Campaign review</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to Experian’s unique and  proprietary data assets to improve campaigns</li>
     </ul>
   </dd>
  <dt>Licensed Services</dt>
   <dd>
    <p><span>As the social space evolves at tremendous speed, even the most experienced in-house teams can need support to stay ahead of the curve.</span></p>
    <p>Experian’s Alchemy Social Licensed solutions offer flexible, on-demand services to meet every need. Our client services team is amongst the most experienced in the industry, offering scalable support to your social strategies and campaigns.</p>
    <p><span>Alchemy SaaS</span></p>
    <p>Licensing the Alchemy Social Platform brings access to the full range of features of the Facebook ads manager platform, including:</p>
     <ul>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Guidance on how to create, manage, report on and optimise campaigns </li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to regular webinars on new releases, features and best practices </li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Dedicated account management support and consultative advice </li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Create campaign rules for real-time cost per acquisition (CPA) optimisation</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Effectively refine activity at various points of the campaign cycle</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Control ad spend at segment level by location or target group</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Analyse conversion data and integrate with other analytical tools</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">View real-time reporting to understand CPA and conversion rates at ad level</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Integrate campaign results with tools like Google Analytics and Adobe Omniture</li>
     </ul> 
    </dd>
  </dl>
```

This is my CSS fro Zebra Accordion:

```css
dl.Zebra_Accordion { width: 100%; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt { background: #000; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dd { background: #EFEFEF; padding: 15px; margin: 1px 0; }
 
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt.Zebra_Accordion_Expanded { background: #C40000; }
```

My jQuery from Zebra Accordion:

```js
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myAccordion = new $.Zebra_Accordion('.Zebra_Accordion', {
        'collapsible':  true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've noticed that it's my CSS that made the layout messy. I'm still in the process of testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one is answering my question I've found out that I just need to change the CSS. It may not be the best accordion out there, but it works well for jQuery 1.5.2 as many accordion plugins failed.

```css
dl.Zebra_Accordion { width: 740px; font-size: 14px; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt { background: #878787; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px;  }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dd { background: #EFEFEF; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 305px; margin: 0; }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt.Zebra_Accordion_Expanded { background: #0095da; }
```

Also, the jQuery snippet didn't work out well so I'm using this one instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  new $.Zebra_Accordion($('.Zebra_Accordion'));
});
```